# my WordPress theme not showing .jpg images only showing .png

Tags: wordpress, jpeg

my WordPress website is not showing JPG images but there is no problem with showing PNG images.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough detail for anyone to help you. You need to include more details, code examples, or something for us to work off of.

Comment: And your question is...

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after I moved a website to another provider, while also changing the domainname. 
In this case .jpeg files were also showing. I used the plugin wp-db-migrate as I always did. 
After trying lots of things and learning that it is really impossible to change the .jpg extension to jpeg) I tried another migration plugin:
the updraftlpus with the [clone/migrate addon](https://updraftplus.com/shop/migrator/). This worked fine.